# How to access all the holdings in an ETF with yahooquery?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, yfinance

Is it possible to grab **all** of the holdings of an ETF within `yahooquery`?

The example code below shows the top 10 holdings of an example ETF, but not all of them. Is it possible to get all the holdings of an ETF within the `yahooquery`/`yfinance` packages?

```
from yahooquery import Ticker

t=Ticker("QQQ")
holdings = t.fund_holding_info['QQQ']['holdings']

holdings = pd.DataFrame.from_records(holdings)
print(holdings)
```

which returns the top 10 holdings of the given ETF.

```
  symbol                 holdingName  holdingPercent
0   MSFT              Microsoft Corp        0.089336
1   AAPL                   Apple Inc        0.086706
2   AMZN              Amazon.com Inc        0.048489
3   NVDA                 NVIDIA Corp        0.045946
4   AVGO                Broadcom Inc        0.043041
5   META  Meta Platforms Inc Class A        0.041650
6   TSLA                   Tesla Inc        0.027246
7  GOOGL        Alphabet Inc Class A        0.025067
8   GOOG        Alphabet Inc Class C        0.024543
9   COST       Costco Wholesale Corp        0.024024
```

If it's not possible with `yahooquery` is there another package that can do it?